# Mmark: path is not on or below dirname

Tags: markdown, rfc

I am using `mmark` to create an RFC from a makdown.

The directory structure is like:

```
myproj
 ├─> paragraphs
 │   ├── 00_abstract.md
 │   ├── 01_introduction.md
 │   └── 02_conclusion.md
 └─> template
     └── main.md
```

I want the paragraphs to be included in `main.md`, for now I am using:

main.md

```
{mainmatter}

{{../paragraphs/01_introduction.md}}

{backmatter}
```

But I get the error: `022/06/21 13:34:45 Failure to read: "/home/euber/Github/protocol-design-assignments/paragraphs/00_abstract.md": path is not on or below "/home/euber/Github/protocol-design-assignments/template"`

How can I solve it? (I don't want to move the paragraphs folder)

Comment: The tool clearly simply disallows you from doing this, no doubt for security reasons.

Comment: If you are sure about this and have reference (e.g. in the doc), I would ask you to put it as a proper answer. I find it strange though, because I am launching the command from the root and not from the ./template folder; it would make more sense to disallow parent folders of the cwd

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is not so sure, but as @tripleee suggested, the tool disallows that, probably for security reasons